# Include a third party script in a functional component of react with server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I'm having trouble inserting a third-party script inside a functional component with server-side rendering.

This is the script I should include in a normal HTML document.

```
<script class="feedaty_sdk" src="https://widget.feedaty.com/public/js/feedaty.js?merchant=******&style_ver=2021" async ></script><div class="feedaty_widget" data-ver="2021" data-id="61fee7f06c9b2" data-type="merchant" data-variant="150x100-1" data-lang="all" data-gui="all"></div>
```

Inside react I created a functional component and within `useEffect`, I created the script.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const FeedatyButton = () => {
 const [scriptLoaded, setScriptLoaded] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
    const feedatyDiv = document.getElementById('feedatyScript');
    if (typeof window !== undefined && !scriptLoaded && !feedatyDiv) {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('async', '');
        script.setAttribute('id', 'feedatyScript');
        script.src =
                'https://widget.feedaty.com/public/js/feedaty.js?merchant=******&style_ver=2021';
        script.addEventListener('load', () => setScriptLoaded(true));
        document.appendChild(script);
    }
  }, []);


  return (
        <div className='flex justify-end items-center' id='feedatyContainer'>
            <div
                className='feedaty_widget'
                data-ver='2021'
                data-id='61fee7f06c9b2'
                data-type='merchant'
                data-variant='150x100-1'
                data-lang='all'
                data-gui='all'></div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default FeedatyButton;
```

The script loads without problem, but nothing appears inside the `feedaty_widget` div.

If I create the div with `createElement` and append it to the document or the body, then it works, but it shows at the end of my react app and obviously, it's not what I want.
I want to place it inside my functional component in a specific position.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong in approach, because I was not updating the component with the code generated by the "feedaty" script.
This is the updated code using ref to update the content

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';

const FeedatyButton = () => {
    const feedatyContainerRef = useRef();
    const [scriptLoaded, setScriptLoaded] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        scriptLoader();
        return () => {
            scriptUnloader();
        };
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!scriptLoaded) return;
    }, [scriptLoaded]);

    const scriptLoader = () => {
        window.addEventListener('load', scriptMover);
        const feedatyDiv = document.getElementById('feedatyScript');
        if (typeof window !== undefined && !feedatyDiv) {
            const script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src =
                'https://widget.feedaty.com/public/js/feedaty.js?merchant=1******&style_ver=2021';
            script.id = 'feedatyScript';
            script.async = true;
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }
    };

    const scriptUnloader = () => {
        window.removeEventListener('load', scriptMover);
        const feedatyDiv = document.getElementById('feedatyScript');
        document.body.removeChild(document.querySelector('#feedatyScript')); 
    };

    // this function get called when script is loaded and i get the content of the widget, so i can update my component using ref
    const scriptMover = () => {
        const feedatyWidgetUpdated = document.getElementById('feedatyWidget');
        feedatyContainerRef.current.appendChild(feedatyWidgetUpdated);
        setScriptLoaded();
    };

    return (
        <div
            className='flex justify-end items-start'
            id='feedatyContainer'
            ref={feedatyContainerRef}>
            <div
                id='feedatyWidget'
                className='feedaty_widget'
                data-id='61fee7f06c9b7'
                data-type='merchant'
                data-variant='150x100-1'
                data-lang='it-IT'
                data-gui='it-IT'></div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default FeedatyButton;
```